# Преобразование координат(преобразование графика функций) для движения персонажа в unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет, вот код клавиши D , который реализует с горем-пополам движение персонажа в сторону(точнее получилось по диагонали, но не суть)

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
```

PosZ = PosZ + speed+PosZ* Time.deltaTime;

```
        Newpos = PosZ;
        Vector3 directionD = new Vector3(Newpos*-1, hero.transform.position.y*-gravity, hero.transform.position.z);
        hero.Move(directionD*Time.deltaTime);
        lastPressedDTimeD = Time.time;
        if (Time.time - lastPressedDTimeA < threshold)
        {
            PosZ = PosZ + PosZ * -1;
        }
    }
```

А вот код клавиши A работает некорректно- персонаж двигается не в ту сторну

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        PosZ = PosZ + speed+PosZ * Time.deltaTime;//к текущей позиции добавили в направлении вперед немного)) 
        Newpos = PosZ;
        Vector3 directionA = new Vector3(Mathf.Sqrt(Newpos*-1), hero.transform.position.y * -gravity,hero.transform.position.z);/*= new Vector3((Newpos * -1) * Mathf.Sqrt(Newpos * -1)*/
        lastPressedDTimeA = Time.time;


        hero.Move(directionA * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Time.time - lastPressedDTimeD < threshold)
        {
            PosX = PosX + PosX * -1;
        }
```

Вод ход моих рассуждений на этот счет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
(синяя стрелка - движение при нажатии клавиши A)

Шаг №2 основан согласно преобразованию
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

именно это, я и пытаюсь реализовать данной клавише, но почему то не выходит.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь реализовать движение вперед/назад/влево/вправо по клавишам `wasd` или что-то еще? Если простое движение, то вы слишком мудрите........ кстати по диагонали должен ходить объект если например зажаты wa или wd или sd или sa? или строго по прямым?

Comment: Да, движение вперед, назад, влево, вправо - по клавишам wasd. Не могли бы Вы подсказать более простой вариант решения данной проблемы?

Comment: нет, когда зажаты клавиши a или d объект должен двигаться строго в сторону - это у меня он почему то двигается по диагонали.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще всё просто. Вы слишком сильно всё усложняете.

Как минимум, очевидные минусы:

- При нажатии <kbd>D</kbd> вы, почему-то, смотрите на `PosZ`, который, очевидно, отвечает за движение по оси Z, которая, в свою очередь, отвечает за движение вперед/назад. Посмотрите рисунок ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всегда помните: Ось Z - вперед/назад, ось X - влево/вправо, ось Y - вверх/вниз.

- Далее, зачем-то, для движения в сторону вы используете гравитацию (gravity). Хотя она должна влиять только на движение вверх. При нажатии <kbd>D</kbd> у вас зачем-то идет учет `hero.transform.position.y*-gravity`
- При движении  по клавише <kbd>А</kbd> вы зачем-то к `PosZ` прибавляете его же и еще PosZ * Time.deltaTime, а потом при применении параметров еще раз умножаете на дельту `hero.Move(directionA * Time.deltaTime);`, что, наверняка изменяет значение не так, как хочется.
  `Time.deltaTime` достаточно применить к конечному оператору в данном случае, чтоб не зависеть от частоты кадров. Остальное излишне, как мне кажется.

Вообще, в самом простом виде, движение за счет `CharacterController` (я вижу метод `Move`, видимо от него) будет выглядеть так:

```
public float speed = 6.0F;
public float gravity = 20.0F;    
public CharacterController hero;

// public float jumpSpeed = 8.0F;  // раскомментировать для прыжка

void Start() {
    hero = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

void Update() {
    Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;

    if (hero.isGrounded) {
        moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
        moveDirection *= speed;

         // раскоментировать для прыжка
         // if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
         //     moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;

    }
    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    hero.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Здесь `Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")` и `Input.GetAxis("Vertical")` - имена осей движения. По умолчанию называются именно так. И по умолчанию `Horizontal` - кнопки <kbd>A</kbd> и <kbd>D</kbd>, `Vertical` (не смотря на название) - кнопки <kbd>W</kbd> и <kbd>S</kbd>. Это все можно посмотреть в настройках 
`Edit`→`Project Settings`→`Input`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эти значения возвращают единичный `Vector3` в зависимости от движения.... Если влево: (-1, 0, 0), вправо - (1, 0, 0), вверх(вперед) - (0, 0, 1), вниз(назад) - (0, 0, -1).

В итоге, за счет этих осей, мы определяем вектор движения и далее уже этот вектор умножаем на скорость и на `Time.deltaTime` и это значение применяем в `hero.Move`.

Что касается гравитации, то мы её, соответствено, применяем только на вектор Y: `moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;`. Не более того.

---

Далее.

По поводу клавиш <kbd>WASD</kbd>. Здесь всё тоже самое. Надо определить направление движения, через единичный вектор, а далее к нему применить скорость и `deltaTime` и закинуть это всё в `Move.`

```
public float speed = 6.0F;
public float gravity = 20.0F;    
public CharacterController hero;

void Start() {
    hero = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) {
        moveDirection = Vector3.forward;  
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) {
        moveDirection = -Vector3.forward;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) {
        moveDirection = -Vector3.right;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) {
        moveDirection = Vector3.right;
    }

    moveDirection *= speed;
    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    hero.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Код, практически идентичен верхнему. Только вместо `Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")` и `Input.GetAxis("Vertical")` мы берем готовые значения полей вектора в Юнити. Тут получается:

```
Vector3.forward = (0, 0, 1)
-Vector3.forward = (0, 0, -1)
Vector3.right = (1, 0, 0)
-Vector3.right = (-1, 0, 0)
```

Единственное, так объект будет двигаться **строго** в строну или вперед/назад. Если при сочетании комбинаций кнопок всторону+вверх/вниз необходимо, чтобы объект двигался по диагонали, то в `moveDirection` надо будет оперировать координатами:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) {
  moveDirection.z = Vector3.forward.z;  
}

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) {
    moveDirection.z = -Vector3.forward.z;
}

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) {
    moveDirection.x = -Vector3.right.x;
}

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) {
    moveDirection.x = Vector3.right.x;
}
```

Всё остальное **без изменений**.

---

Надеюсь всё понятно.

Остальные свои условия, в виде `lastPressedDTimeA = Time.time;` и что вам необходимо, думаю, добавите уже сами... на логику движения оно не влияет (пока этого вы не захотите сделать).

Comment: Ниче се........

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Ну дык........